# Wireless mouse freezing if I don't move it for a few seconds until I click

Tags: wireless, mouse

I recently installed Kubuntu 20.04, in my laptop computer (hp af116la) and I found this problem when I connect my hp wireless mouse to any USB port on my computer.

It just stops moving if I don't move it for a few seconds (5 seconds approx.) until I click any button again (left, right, or middle wheel).

I found [this solution](https://superuser.com/questions/408683/why-my-usb-mouse-gets-suspended-after-3-seconds-of-inactivity), but it's too old (8 years) and I didn't find the files or the package laptop-mode-tools that are supposed to be modified to make it work again.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is fairly old, but I had the same issue and it can be fixed pretty easily by identifying your mouses bus id, then blacklisting it from autosuspend.
Basically, laptop-mode-tools suspends things to save power, and it autosuspends after the set duration, which I believe is 2sec default.

**Step 1:** Open terminal: `lsusb`
-Identify USB mouse, copy busID

**Step 2:** Navigate to /etc/laptop-mode/conf.d

```
cd /etc/laptop-mode/conf.d
```

**Step 3:** In terminal: `sudoedit runtime-pm.conf`

**Step 4a:** navigate to line 40, or the next empty line under

```
"# The list of Device IDs that should not use autosuspend. Use system commands or
# look into sysfs to find out the IDs of your devices.
# Example: AUTOSUSPEND_RUNTIME_DEVID_BLACKLIST="046d:c025 0123:abcd""
```

and copy:

```
AUTOSUSPEND_RUNTIME_DEVID_BLACKLIST=""
```

**Step 4b:** Paste this in the line below the example, then add the busID you copied earlier into the quotes. It should look something like this:

```
# The list of Device IDs that should not use autosuspend. Use system commands or
# look into sysfs to find out the IDs of your devices.
# Example: AUTOSUSPEND_RUNTIME_DEVID_BLACKLIST="046d:c025 0123:abcd"
AUTOSUSPEND_RUNTIME_DEVID_BLACKLIST="1bcf:0005"
```

**Step 5:** press CTRL-O (or however you prefer to save and exit),  and then you should be good to go.

You can also just outright disable autosuspend by editing line 29 (Below "enable Runtime autosuspend feature"), and you can also change the autosuspend duration by editing line 66 (Below "# Auto-Suspend timeout in seconds").

Note: For older version of Ubuntu (this is on 20.04.3 LTS), there may be a .conf file specifically for usb autosuspend, so you may have to edit that rather than the runtime-pm.conf file.

Commands:

```
lsusb

cd /etc/laptop-mode/conf.d 

sudoedit runtime-pm.conf
```